# Condition selection

Tags: r, dataframe, selection

I have 4 different people and they have 5 values assigned to them.

```
A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  Name
5   6   7   2   5   Tom
10  4   4   1   4   Suzie
2   3   5   1   5   Fred
5   5   2   5   1   Tom
```

I have all these values stored in a data frame called `Data`

I want to retrieve all the `A1` values where `Name == "Tom"`

First attempt:

```
if(Data$Name = "Tom") A1Vals <- Data$A1
```

Second attempt:

```
if(Data$Name = "Tom") c(A1Vals, Data$A1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Data[Data$Name=="Tom", "A1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subset`

```
subset(Data, Name == "Tom", select = A1)
```

or the `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
select(filter(Data, Name == "Tom"), A1)
```